# An invalid argument was supplied after socket timed out

Tags: python, sockets, lan

I'm new to python. Written in python 3.6

You can skip ipRange part

This is the code:

```
import socket

def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   temp = start
   ip_range = []

   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while temp != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))    

   return ip_range

ip_range = ipRange("192.168.0.101", "192.168.0.110")
#To this point everything is fine since it is not my code

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(5)
# if i add s.setblocking(1) it works, but it is really slow and not printing 
# out "timed out" error message

for ip in ip_range:
    try:
        con = s.connect((ip, 80))
        con.close()
    except Exception as msg:
        print(ip, msg)
```

**I want this code to** print out ip and exception msg "ConnectionRefusedError" or socket "timed out" error only **but** after the "timed out" error every single next exception msg is "An invalid argument was supplied".

Shell:

```
192.168.0.101 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the 
target machine actively refused it                              #Good
192.168.0.102 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target 
machine actively refused it                                     #Good
192.168.0.103 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target 
machine actively refused it                                     #Good
192.168.0.104 timed out                                         #Good
192.168.0.105 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied #Not good
192.168.0.106 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied #
192.168.0.107 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied 
192.168.0.108 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied 
192.168.0.109 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied 
192.168.0.110 [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Everything is fine until "timed out" msg. After that i want it to print "timed out" msg again for the next IP or print out "ConnectionRefusedError" - which means device is connected to that ip on lan.

Later on i will try to make this script print out all devices which are connected to lan.

I hope you got the point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never catch bare `Exception`. Instead, catch specifically what you want to handle. In this case, `except socket.timeout`, I believe.

Comment: Also the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module may already do what `ipRange` does for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch socket timeout in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442710/how-to-catch-socket-timeout-in-python-3)

Comment: If there is no device to connect - i need it to print _timed out_ **and then** scan the next IP address **but** instead of printing out _ConnectionRefusedError_ msg or again _timed out_, it prints out _An invalid argument was supplied_ for every next IP address. @BaileyParker

Comment: I was suggesting you use an `IPv4Network` and iterate over it to the subnet you are attempting to scan. As for the error, perhaps try using contexts (`with s.connect((ip, 80)): pass`)? I'm not too familiar with windows sockets but it could be a race between timing out, close, and socket reuse.

Comment: As for the original error, i still haven't found solution, but i guess i'm just gonna use `ipaddress` module instead. Thank you. @BaileyParker